# LINQ Datagridview to comma delimited string

Tags: c#, linq

Hello is there a way to create a comma delimited string from an entire row from a datagridview.

Currently what I've been doing is something like so:

```
for(int y = 0; y < datagridview1.Rows.Count; y++)
{
    List<string> List = new List<string>();
    for(int x = 0; x < datagridview1.Columns.Count; x++)
    {
        List.Add(datagridview.Row[y].Cells[x].Value.ToString());
        //here i write it to a file doing something like string.Join(",",List)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use LINQ or is there a way that I can condense this to a one liner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to emulate a `for` loop on integers:

```
var res = Enumerable.Range(0, datagridview1.Rows.Count)
    .Select(y => Enumerable.Range(0, datagridview1.Columns.Count)
        .Select(x => datagridview.Row[y].Cells[x].Value.ToString())
        .ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: And to make it a coma delimited string:  string final = string.join(",", res);

Answer (score 0):

The row and cell collections are all enumerable so you could make better use of LINQ here.  You don't need to index the rows and columns, just enumerate over them.

```
var data =
    (from DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView.Rows
    select String.Join(",",
        from DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells
        select c.Value
    )).ToList();
```